# How to disassemble Dell Inspiron 1501?

Tags: power-supply, dell-inspiron

I can get the hard drive out and all the screws out of the back, but it doesn't come apart.  I'm guessing that it's like many others and requires the keyboard to come out to get at more screws.  Unfortunately I don't see how, and Google is failing me.  Anyone else manage to get it apart successfully?

Exact problem in question is a complete failure to accept power.  2 power adapters tried, absolutely nothing lighting up.

Comment: This may help, if you haven't already seen it. It's the service manual http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins1501/en/sm_en/index.htm

Comment: Great!  I could only find the user manual on Dell's site and Google didn't find anything either.  Thank you!

Comment: @barlop's comment here is actually the right answer for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the Dell Inspiron 1501  service manual  (dell calls it the service manual).

googling for dell inspiron 1501 service manual  gives link

https://ifixit-documents.s3.amazonaws.com/jhM2Q4L1lMJxHErQ.pdf

and in case Dell misbehave and change the link

https://web.archive.org/web/20160910192551/https://ifixit-documents.s3.amazonaws.com/jhM2Q4L1lMJxHErQ.pdf

dead old link
<s>http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins1501/en/sm_en/index.htm</s>

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: @ElderGeek hmm, and archive.org haven't got pics. New link is there.

Comment: Pictures are nice, but logic will do the trick. +1

Comment: pictures on how to disassemble it are important, but it's fine, they're in the PDF file

Answer (score 3):

Disassembly guide: http://www.ehow.com/how_6393241_apart-dell-inspiron-1501-laptop.html

Comment: Doh.  Except it doesn't match the one I have here.  They must have more than 1 type of Inspiron 1501.  This one doesn't have a single "M" screw, it has 2 "C/M", and once all the bottom screws are removed, it doesn't actually come apart...